# Eclipse J2EE Web Module Project Type

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I am trying to create a simple Java HTTP Servlet inside of eclipse, however, under the Web folder in the project wizard i do not have an option for J2EE Web Module as many tutorials have indicated, i only have Dynamic and Static Web Projects.  just a little background, i am trying to simply build a small servlet that i am then exposing via JBoss Web on one of my web servers.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to create a **Dynamic Web Project**? That should be it.

Comment: ...which requires "Eclipse for Java **EE** developers" having installed (or installing the WTP plugin separately)